# Cannot send HTTP request to subdomain alias

Tags: c++, http, subdomain

I have a php page on a website I am trying to send HTTP requests to through C++. This webpage is being run through my school which loves to use subdomains.

The page is on one domain, SubA.xxx.website.edu. When I lookup the address, I find out that SubA.xxx.website.edu is an alias for SubB.xxx.website.edu, and I get returned the IP address for SubB.

The problem is SubB.xxx.website.edu/precise/page.php does not lead me to the same place as SubA.xxx.webiste.edu/precise/page.php. How can I specify I want to access SubA.xxx.website.edu in HTTP? I can only get the IP for xxx.website.edu.

Here is my code for clarification (after creating a UNIX socket)

```
string mes;
mes = "GET /precise/page.html HTTP/1.1\n";
mes += "Host: ";
mes += argv[1];  // URL or IP of webpage 
mes += "\n\n";
send(s, mes.c_str(), mes.length(), 0);
```

Comment: What library are you using to do this?

Comment: In HTTP, lines should be separated with `"\r\n"`, not `"\n"` alone.

Comment: I am using these libraries:

sys/types.h

sys/socket.h

sys/netinet/in.h

arpa/inet.h

netdb.h

unistd.h

Comment: Are you checking the response? Is the server telling you to look in a different place?

Comment: the response I am getting is just a 404, also thank you Igor for the tip, I am new to HTTP

Comment: These are probably virtual hosts and the web server redirects you to the right content depending on the full domain you visit. Therefore you cannot get the content through the ip because it is the same for all sites but rather through its full domain.

Comment: @fassl when I do the full request I get the same IP. I need the IP number specifically, I am trying to connect with a device that doesnt have a function similar to getHostByName()

Comment: @bobdriving: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=956729. Seems like in the GET you should put the ip and url and in the Host header you specify subA.xxx...